# how can I select this text in html?

Tags: beautifulsoup

I want to select only this text "35,941 ~ 44,100" by using Beautifulsoup. but, there is no tag for it, I can select it by 'soup.find)

```
<span id="list_price">35,941 ~ 44,100<span class="txt_unit_price">원</span><i class="ic-18-line-arrow-bottom"></i></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find the tag by its HTML `id` using `.find(id='list_price')`. And then use `.find_next()` to *only* get the price:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """<span id="list_price">35,941 ~ 44,100<span class="txt_unit_price">원</span><i class="ic-18-line-arrow-bottom"></i></span>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

print(soup.find(id="list_price").find_next(text=True))
```

Output:

```
35,941 ~ 44,100
```

**Edit**

If you inspect your network calls, you'll see that the prices are loaded dynamically by sending a `GET` request to:

```
https://www.musinsa.com/app/svc/member_price_new/1848166/0?&type=detail
```

You can get the prices with:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.musinsa.com/app/svc/member_price_new/1848166/0?&type=detail"
PATTERN = re.compile(r"\d+,\d+")
HEADERS = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.75 Safari/537.36"
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS).content, "html.parser")

print(
    PATTERN.search(
        str(soup.select_one("li:last-of-type span.txt_price_member"))
    ).group(0)
)

print(
    PATTERN.search(
        str(soup.select_one("li:first-of-type span.txt_price_member"))
    ).group(0)
)
```

Output:

```
35,941
44,100
```

Comment: what if you don't have the html_doc? I mean you have only this URL(https://www.musinsa.com/app/goods/1848166?loc=goods_rank)

Comment: @lupalupa See my edit

Comment: You solution using re  is really praiseworthy